# Create a new mode in 3D View

Tags: python, blender

#### Info

blender 2.74

#### Problem

I want to create a new mode in the 3D view of Blender for learning purpose. And I could not find anything about that in the internet. The goal is to create a completely new mode besides the object mode and the sculp mode (name: creative mode). Is this possible? If yes, does anyone have a code snippet or a tip I can base my application on?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that is possible through python.

If you start with [DNA_object_types.h](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/makesdna/DNA_object_types.h), at the bottom you will find the ObjectMode enum that defines the modes available. Find where these are used to find a way to patch in your new mode.